# Main component gets data one step later than its child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "main" component, that has a child component, which has a search form.

Even though nothing works yet, I want to make sure that my main component gets the value I type in the search bar. However, I noticed my main component gets the data one step later than my child component.

**Main Component**

```
export default class MainComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.state = {input: null};
  }

  handleFilterInput(value) {
    this.setState({input: value});
    console.log(this.state.input);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChilComponent handleFilterInput={this.handleFilterInput.bind(this)}/>

      // Rest of the component
    )
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

  onFieldChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.props.handleFilterInput(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          label="Search"
          margin="normal"
          name="search"
          onChange={this.onFieldChange.bind(this)}
          type="text"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are both a `console.log` in the main component and the main component. Let's say I want to type "article", the result will be the following:

```
child_component.js:21 a
main.js:116 *null*
child_component.js:21 ar
main.js:116 a
child_component.js:21 art
main.js:116 ar
child_component.js:21 arti
main.js:116 art
child_component.js:21 artic
main.js:116 arti
child_component.js:21 articl
main.js:116 artic
child_component.js:21 article
main.js:116 articl
```

What is happening, why, and how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState()` is asynchronous, so when you attempt to `console.log(this.state.input)` right after calling `this.setState()`, your state has not yet been updated.

In the `ChildComponent`, you are logging the data right from the event, which happens in real time.

If you wanted your Main Component to log the same, you could do:

```
handleFilterInput(value) {
    this.setState({input: value}, () => console.log(this.state.input));
```

}

The second parameter to `setState()` is a function that executes when the state has been updated.

You could also use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` in your Main Component:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.input);
}
```

Comment: So, does it means that even though I don't see the right element inside my console, the result is already good, but it was good after the console.log displayed the result?

Comment: yeah - your state is updating to the same value, but just not yet at the point you were logging

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'm still having hard times with asynchroneous stuff :)